# Birational map of surfaces with target nonsingular

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There is a question in a certain well-known textbook that goes like this.

> > Let $f:X'\rightarrow X$ be a birational morphism of surfaces (integral separated schemes of dimension two and of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$) and suppose $X$ is complete nonsingular with function field $K$. Moreover assume that there is a closed point $x_0\in X$ and an irreducible curve $Y'\subset X'$ with $f(Y')=x_0$. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y'$; then $f(\eta)=x_0$. Let $R$ be the local ring of $\eta$; then $R$ is a DVR with center at $x_0$ on $X$.

If one assumes $X'$ is nonsingular, it is obvious. If one doesn't, then it is false. See comments.

Comment: You are correct.  You do need to assume that $X'$ is normal at the generic point $\eta$ of $Y'$ in order to conclude that $R$ is a DVR.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks – do you have an example?

Comment: "do you have an example?"  The simplest example that I can think of is the following.  Let $X$ be $\mathbb{P}^2_k = \text{Proj}\ k[s,t,u]$.  Let $r>1$ be an integer.  Denote $\text{Proj}\ k[\sigma,\tau]$ by $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.  Let $X'\subset \mathbb{P}^2_k\times_k \mathbb{P}^1_k$ be the zero scheme of the bihomogeneous polynomial $\sigma^r t - \tau^r s$.  Let $f:X'\to X$ be the restriction to $X'$ of the projection $\text{pr}_1$.  Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{P}^2_k$ be the closed point $[s,t,u]=[0,0,1]$.  Let $Y'$ be $\{x_0\}\times \mathbb{P}^1_k$.